# Segmentation errors(core dumped) after deleting pointers

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a mask delivery, ordering service code.
The function `order` will add a new order to order list.
The function `output` will output the list from newest to oldest order.
The function `deliver` removes the oldest order.
The following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Mask {
    string type;
    string customer;
    Mask *next;
};

void order(Mask *&head, string type, string customer){
    cout << "Ordering " << type << " for " << customer << endl;
    Mask *oldHead = head;
    head = new Mask;
    head->type = type;
    head->customer = customer;
    head->next = oldHead;
}

void output(Mask *head){
    cout << "Outputting order list " << endl;
    for (Mask *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        cout << "  " << p->type << " for " << p->customer << endl;
}
void deliver(Mask *&head){
    if (head->next == NULL){
        cout << "Delivering " << head->type;
        cout << " for " << head->customer << endl;
        delete head;
    }
    else
        deliver(head->next);
}
int main()
{
    Mask *head = NULL;
    order(head, "3M-N95", "Alice");
    order(head, "OxyAir", "Burce");
    order(head, "3M-N95", "Cindy");
    output(head);
    deliver(head);
    output(head);
}
```

Everything runs smoothly, but it says segmentation error(core dumped) at the end. I tried adding this:

```
if (head->next->next == NULL){
  deliver(head->next);
  head->next == NULL;
}
```

But the problem still exists. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you try reading, outloud, what's happening in `deliver`, the problem should be obvious. For example, after the `delete head;` part, when the execution continues, what do you think will happen in the immediately-following `if (...)` statement? And what do you think will happen when `head` is deleted, to the caller's `head`? How does the caller know that the `head` has been `delete`d, and its pointer is no longer valid?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `deliver` to this:

```
void deliver(Mask *&head){
    if (head->next->next == NULL){
        cout << "Delivering " << head->next->type;
        cout << " for " << head->next->customer << endl;
        head->next = head->next->next;
        delete head->next;
    }
    else
        deliver(head->next);
}
```

Apparently, just setting the pointer to NULL does not fix the problem, so I just updated it so that the second last pointer pointed directly to the end.

Answer (score 0):

in "deliver" you force the function to meet the condition `if(head->next == NULL)`
and then trying to reach `head->next->next` which is like trying to say null->next (resulting with segmentation fault).
I would recommend traversing to the last "Mask" object with a while loop instead of using all those "if" statements which lead to the same result, or at least change the second if to `else if` in order to avoid meeting this "if" again.